# How to parse an audio file and download it by jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I try to parse the mp3 file in a website by jsoup.
I write a code in this way:

```
String url = "http://www.xeno-canto.org/explore?query=Haemorhous+mexicanus+&dir=0&order=loc";
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        System.out.println(doc.title());
        Elements h1s = doc.getElementsByTag("div>audio[src]");    

        Element thisOne = null;
        for(Iterator it = h1s.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        {
            thisOne = (Element)it.next();
            System.out.println(thisOne.html());
        }
```

While there are many layer of `<div>` in html, I don't know if I can ask for things under `<audio>` tag in this way. The html looks like this:

```html
<div class="jp-player jp-player-219351" id="p_xc_audio_219351_883" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"><img id="jp_poster_17" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: none;"><audio id="jp_audio_17" preload="none" src="http://www.xeno-canto.org/sounds/uploaded/RFTXRYBVBX/XC219351-House%20Finch%20calls%20and%20then%20calls%20in%20flight%20-CA%2C%20TRV%2C%20March%2003%2C%20%E2%80%8E2012%2C%201045%20AM.mp3"></audio></div>
```

My goal is to parse and download the mp3 file under all the audio[src] tags, but it didn't succeed after trying many times. Hope someone could give me any hint for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using this code:

```
String url = "http://www.xeno-canto.org/explore?query=Haemorhous+mexicanus+&dir=0&order=loc";
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

    System.out.println(doc.title());
    Elements h1s = doc.select(".jp-type-single");
    System.out.println("Number of results: " + h1s.size());
    for (Element element : h1s) {
        String mp3Url = element.attr("data-xc-filepath");
        System.out.println("mp3 url: " + mp3Url);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Some suggestions:

- [`doc.getElementsByTag(String tagName)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementsByTag-java.lang.String-) accepts a tag name and not a CSS query. If you want to select in this way you should use [`select(String cssQuery)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#select-java.lang.String-);
- don't use an `Iterator` to loop [`Elements`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) but a foreach because it extends `java.util.ArrayList<Element>` and it's simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Davide so much!
I parse all those mp3 files successfully only use 2 more minutes!
I add the standard IO to save the file and the whole code looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int file_num =0;

    for(int page=1; page <=7; page++){

        String url = "http://www.xeno-canto.org/explore?query=Haemorhous+mexicanus+&dir=0&order=loc&pg="+page;

        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

            System.out.println(doc.title());
            Elements h1s = doc.select(".jp-type-single"); 
            System.out.println("Number of results: " + h1s.size());
            for (Element element : h1s) { 
                String mp3Url = element.attr("data-xc-filepath"); 
                System.out.println("mp3 url: " + mp3Url);
                file_num++;

                URLConnection conn = new URL(mp3Url).openConnection();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

                OutputStream outstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("/users/pelican/downloads/"+file_num+"file.mp3"));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                int len;
                while ((len = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
                }
                outstream.close();           
            }
        }   catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


    }  
}
```